# Pitch accent of nominalizers

Tags: nominalization, pitch-accent

Do the nominalizers "no" and "koto" have recessive accent (i.e. no downstep) or downstep after the first syllable? Or are they enclitic (i.e. unaccented unless following a word with no downstep in which case they accent the final syllable, like だ)?

Answer (score 8):

- **の** (not same pattern with *the postposition の*!)

  - after *accentless verbs and na-adjectives*: downstep before the particle

    > なる{LH} "make sound" → なるの{LHL}
    >
    > かえる{LHH} "change (t.)" → かえるの{LHHL}
    >
    > みつめる{LHHH} "stare at" → みつめるの{LHHHL}
    >
    > せいかくだ{LHHHH} "accurate" → せいかくなの{LHHHHL}
  - after *accented verbs and na-adjectives*: keeps the pitch

    > なる{HL} "become" → なるの{HLL}
    >
    > かえる{HLL} "go home" → かえるの{HLLL}
    >
    > につめる{LHHL} "boil down (t.)" → につめるの{LHHLL}
    >
    > ふせいかくだ{LHLLLL} "inaccurate" → ふせいかくなの{LHLLLLL}
  - after *i-adjectives*: always downstep before い

    > あつい{LHH} "thick" → あついの{LHLL}
    >
    > あつい{LHL} "hot" → あついの{LHLL}
- **こと**

  - after *accentless words*: takes over the accent (final syllable)

    > なる{LH} → なること{LHHH} → なることが{LHHHL}
    >
    > かえる{LHH} → かえること{LHHHH} → かえることが{LHHHHL}
    >
    > みつめる{LHHH} → みつめること{LHHHHH} → みつめることが{LHHHHHL}
    >
    > あつい{LHH} → あついこと{LHHHH} → あついことが{LHHHHL}
    >
    > せいかくだ{LHHHH} → せいかくなこと{LHHHHHH} → せいかくなことが{LHHHHHHL}
  - after *accented words*: keeps the pitch

    > なる{HL} → なること{HLLL}
    >
    > かえる{HLL} → かえること{HLLLL}
    >
    > につめる{LHHL} → につめること{LHHLLL}
    >
    > あつい{LHL} → あついこと{LHLLL}
    >
    > ふせいかくだ{LHLLLL} → ふせいかくなこと{LHLLLLLL}

A verb or adjective whose last syllable is high is always accentless. The list of word accents is available from, for example, [here](http://accent.u-biq.org/english.html).

Comment: Are you sure about 事? OJAD lists こと as Odaka, even after accented nouns. I didn't see any information in NHK that こと loses its accent after accented words.

Comment: @George Generally, 形式名詞 doesn't inherit its accent as standalone noun. こと's accentuation in なる{HL}こと is kind of difficult to specify with this notation. In short, it does not make another accent phrase, but optionally has one more downstep at the end like a "secondary accent".

Comment: Re: こと after accentless words, is 頭高型 also an admissible pitch pattern? I feel like I hear さがすことが{LHHHLL} quite a lot, perhaps even more often than さがすことが{LHHHHL}.

Comment: @dekinai Indeed, I occasionally hear that accent too, while I still believe that 尾高 is the prescriptive one. I can at least find one paper on this matter: https://ir.library.osaka-u.ac.jp/repo/ouka/all/8856/19-04.pdf. It doesn't have a clear conclusion, but says personal variation and prominence largely contribute to the 頭高 shift.