# Pronunciation of ことばかり

Tags: pitch-accent, particle-ばかり

At [5m18s](https://youtu.be/nSqrgTEpHmM?t=318), the speaker says

> 悪い**ことばかり**しています

with pronunciation ことばかり{LHHLL}. Even OJAD agrees with this pronunciation:

> [image]

**Question:** I thought こと was Odaka, so shouldn't this be ことばかり{LHLLL}?

Comment: 「[わるいことばかり]{LHLLLHLL}しています。」に聞こえるような気が。。

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66619/7810, especially see my comment.

Comment: It consists of 悪いこと and ばかり with each pronounced with its own accent contour, not of 悪い and ことばかり. It does no good to check the accent pattern of ことばかり.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm still a bit confused why the particle ばかり has an accent on its first mora, given it's a particle attached to 悪いこと (taken as a singular word with a downstep before *its* final mora). So it seems like it should be わるいことばかり{LHLLLLLL} when applying the pitch rules naively?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a mere basic rule for which there're lots of exceptions. See bottom p11 http://corismus.com/intonation/works/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E%E3%83%BB%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E%E9%A1%9E%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%882020MS.pdf